# Issue passing value from textbox to jquery function and onto controller function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I came across an issue with passing values to jQuery where I want to pass the value from a textbox.

Here is the `.cshtml`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "orderNumber" })
```

My script:

```
function maintenance_tapped(e) {
    var data = $('#orderNumber').val();

    $("#SapPopUp")
        .dialog({
            width: 600,
            height: 420,
            model: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveOrder", "Home")',
                        data: data,
                        type: "POST"
                    }).done(function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Code in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> RetrieveOrder(string number)
{
    if (_sapHelper == null)
    {
        _sapHelper = new Helper();
    }

    return View();
}
```

My issue is that if I put a breakpoint in the `RetrieveOrder` function and I check the value of `number` i get `null`.

Then if go into `Chrome->inspect element->Console` and type `$('#orderNumber').val()`, I get the value I entered into the textbox.

It also seems like its not passing the value into the function.

Comment: I don't think it knows how to bind your number. I recommend changing the method signature of `RetriveOrder` to `RetrieveOrder(string orderNumber)`.

Comment: still equals `null`

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: In the "OK" function, can you `console.log(data);` and see if that scope has access to the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dataType :'json',
data: {number: data},
```

Comment: A step closer I guess. `number ` now equals "" rather than `null`

Comment: Try adding dataType :'json',

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the value in a javascript object and match the key to your action's parameter name.

This should work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveOrder", "Home")',
    data: {
        number: $('#orderNumber').val()
    },
    type: "POST"
}).done(function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
});
```

Also, I see you are returning a viewresult from the action method, but not using that in your ajax method call's done/success event handler. What is the point of doing that?

Comment: its unfinished code :-) it will do something eventually, just testing things out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this thanks to Aleksander Matic and Rob Lang.

Soloution

```
function maintenance_tapped(e) {
//var data = $('#orderNumber').val(); <------- Remove from here

$("#SapPopUp")
    .dialog({
        width: 600,
        height: 420,
        model: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                var data = $('#orderNumber').val(); //<--------- Place here
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveOrder", "Home")',
                    data: data,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType :'json',      //<-------- Added
                    data: {number: data},  //<-------- Added
                }).done(function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                });
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```